# Getting Meteor 0.9.1.1 click event to update object

Tags: javascript, events, meteor, click, updates

I'm just playing around with different patterns and am very new to programming, however I've got everything to work in my test app so far except this. I've tried a bunch of variations with no luck, but I suspect I'm missing something really simple.

Basically what I want to happen is for a user to click a button and for it to then update the value of two specific attributes of the current object.

In this example I'm wanting the update to occur when the user clicks the "Return" button (the other buttons shown below are working fine).

Here's the HTML template for the button in question:

```
<template name="bookDetails">
<div class="post">
    <div class="post-content">
            <h3>{{title}}</h3><span> {{author}}</span>

    {{#if onLoan}}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    On loan to: {{lender}}{{/if}}
    </div>


        {{#if ownBook}}
            <a href="{{pathFor 'bookEdit'}}" class="discuss btn">Edit</a>
            <a href="{{pathFor 'bookLoan'}}" class="discuss btn">Lend</a>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <a class="discuss btn return" href="">Return </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Here's the .js file which contains my Template event. Basically I want to set the values for the "lendstatus" and "lender" attributes.

```
Template.bookDetails.helpers({
  ownBook: function() {
    return this.userId == Meteor.userId();
  },
  onLoan: function() {
    return this.lendstatus == 'true';
  }
});

Template.bookLoan.events({
  'click .return': function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var currentBookId = this._id;
     var bookProperties = {
       lendstatus: "false",
       lender: "",
    }

   Books.update(currentBookId, {$set: bookProperties}, function(error) {
      if (error) {
      // display the error to the user
      throwError(error.reason);
      } else {
      Router.go('bookPage', {_id: currentBookId});
      }
    });
   },
 });
```

If I type the following into the Browser console while on the page for the object with id ZLDvXZ9esfp8yEmJu I get the correct behaviour on screen and the database updates so I know I'm close:

```
Books.update({ _id: "ZLDvXZ9esfp8yEmJu"}, {$set: {lendstatus: "false", lender: ""}});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you using autopublish or your own publications ? Have you logged the currentBookId in your event handler to see if it's correct ? Your event handler should be defined on the bookDetails not bookLoan template.

Comment: Thanks @saimeunt! Your last statement solved my problem - Once I defined it in the right template it all worked fine

Answer (score 1):

OK - so my problem was that I'd defined the event handler in the wrong template. I'd defined it in the bookLoan template instead of the bookDetails template. Thanks @saimeunt for pointing this out!